# Issue with ToolTip bound to a dependency property

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I am facing an issue with ToolTips (again!)..

My code is as follows:

Xaml file:

```
<Grid>
        <Button Height="23" Margin="82,0,120,105" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Label, Mode=Default}">Button</Button>        
    </Grid>
```

cs file:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        Parameter p1;
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            p1 = new Parameter();
            p1.Label = "One thing";
            this.DataContext = p1;

            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(aTimer_Elapsed);
            aTimer.Interval = 5000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        void aTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            aTimer.Enabled = false;
            p1.Label = null;
        }        

    }
```

The Parameter class is as follows:

```
class Parameter : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

        private string label = String.Empty;

        public string Label
        {
            get { return label; }
            set
            {
                label = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Label"));
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, propertyChangedEventArgs);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Now after the button is clicked, I get the tooltip "One thing" but after 5 seconds, I get an empty tooltip for sometime. Since I set the dependency property to null, I had expected no tooltip.

Afterwards, if I hover the mouse over the button, I get no empty ToolTip (as expected). Its only during the change of value I get the empty ToolTip.

Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... change your `Label` property and `_label` variable to type `object` instead of `string` i.e. use it as string but declare it as an `object`.

I guess the problem above happens because `null` string is actually `string.Empty` and `ToolTip` is of object type. The boxing that happens assumes null string as `string.empty` and hence shows a empty tooltip instead of no tooltip. But if `Label` is object tyupe then null value will represent no `ToolTip`.

If the suggested data type change of the `Label` property is not allowed in your case then then use a `Converter` in the `Label` binding to return null object for empty string.

Let me know if this helps.